# I can't switch to a frame using its name with no ID defined using Webdriver (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Here is the html:

```
<frame name="Chooser" scrolling="YES" src="/Dispatcher?page=JobSkillsRolesEntry&sig=ZUVPdTRjeGNoSDM2cFBXNDZPc3RBam5uLzZzPTtZMlJsTVRaak1UVXRNakE1WXkwME9USmlMVGt4TkdJdFltSXdZV1ZrTVRreU9UWXg7cGFnZQ%3D%3D" marginheight=0 noresize>
<frameset rows="70,*" framespacing=0 frameborder="1">
    <frame name="SkillSearch" scrolling="NO" src="/Dispatcher?page=skillsRolesSearchPage&sig=WllqYlZRekpKMXV1RlVmOW1FaWlQQ3BXS0tjPTtZMlJsTVRaak1UVXRNakE1WXkwME9USmlMVGt4TkdJdFltSXdZV1ZrTVRreU9UWXg7cGFnZQ%3D%3D" marginheight=0 noresize>
    <frame name="SkillList" scrolling="YES" src="/Dispatcher?page=categoryPage&sig=dytiNVRQayswWUJISzF0TGxJNVQ1MFpCZFM0PTtZMlJsTVRaak1UVXRNakE1WXkwME9USmlMVGt4TkdJdFltSXdZV1ZrTVRreU9UWXg7cGFnZQ%3D%3D" marginheight=0>
</frameset>
```

and here is the code that works using the frames index:

```
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent().switchTo().frame(0);
    logger.info("Found Chooser Frame");
    driver.switchTo().frame(1);
    logger.info("Found SkillSearch Frame");
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent().switchTo().frame(0);
    driver.switchTo().frame(2);
    logger.info("Found SkillList Frame");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a")).click();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Here is the code that doesnt work when I use the name:

```
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent().switchTo().frame("Chooser");
    logger.info("Found Chooser Frame");
    driver.switchTo().frame("SkillSearch");
    logger.info("Found SkillSearch Frame");
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent().switchTo().frame("Chooser");
    driver.switchTo().frame("SkillList");
    logger.info("Found SkillList Frame");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a")).click();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

I would like to use the name because its cleaner. Any ideas

Comment: Which line isn't working?  What is the error?  What version of Selenium?  What browser and version is this running against?

Comment: sorry should have added that . Selenium 2.35.0 Firefox 24.0 and the first switch using the name "Chooser". Works fine using index

Comment: i've **never** seen `.defaultContent()` used.. **ever**.. Why do you need that? maybe that's what's causing it?

Comment: wait a minute - is that frameset nested?  if so, i've tried to investigate this issue in the selenium source and rectify it myself, but no dice.  I've written an issue here - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6389

Comment: Yes this is a nested frameset. and thanks for opening an issue. For the nearterm I'll continue to use the frame index.

Comment: Yes this is a nested frameset. and thanks for opening an issue. For the near term I'll continue to use the frame index. As for the defaultContent() I use that to return to the mainFrame. Whenever I use multiple frames I've always needed to follow the exact frame path to access nested frame elements. Just to make sure I pulled the defaultContent() switchTo and verified it did not work.